# How does AWS charge for Elastic Inference accelerator?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand how AWS charges for Elastic Inference accelerators. The [relevant page](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/elastic-inference/pricing/) says:

> you pay only for the accelerator hours you use

But I can see two possible readings of that:

1. The hours that an EC2 instance with an EI accelerator attached to it runs.
2. The hours that the EC2 instance actually accesses/engages the EI accelerator.

The difference can be significant: the EC2 instance can do some other stuff apart from running EI, and only engage it from time to time (even though it remains attached/accessible *all* the time).

The linked page gives two examples where the prices for EC2 and EI are simply combined, which suggests that option #1 above probably applies. But, it could simply mean that in those particular examples the EC2 instances run the attached EI accelerators non-stop all the time i.e. there is no time when the instance runs but the accelerator is idling.

Can someone please clarify how the charges work?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the page is imprecise. Based on what other services do, I expect that you pay for the time the accelerator is attached to your EC2 instance, as you have reserved that hardware for your exclusive use.

Comment: I'm not too sure about "reserved hardware for exclusive use". EI is a network-attached device which, presumably, leverages a shared pool of GPUs, so, when it is not used (albeit attached), the GPUs in the pool should be available for other EI accelerators.

Comment: Yeah. You really need to ask AWS this question. Billing support is free.